# Topological definition of continuity on a real valued function with removable discontinuity

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Consider some constant function $f(x)=c$, $f(x_0)=0$, for $c\neq 0$. This function is obviously discontinuous as $x_0$, so according to the topological definition of continuity, there must exist an open set $U\subset \mathbb{R}$ such that $f^{-1}(U)$ is not open. I'm having trouble finding such a set.

Naturally, I would want to consider the interval $(c-\epsilon, c+\epsilon)$ for some $\epsilon<c$, but the preimage of this is $(-\infty, x_0)\cup (x_0, \infty)$, which is open.

Thanks so much!

Comment: You mean "there must exist an open set $U\subseteq\mathbf{R}$ such that $f^{-1}(U)$ is *not* open."

Comment: Quite right! Thank you for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try looking at a small $\epsilon$-neighborhood around $0$ - its preimage will only contain the singleton $\{x_0\}$.

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense! What if the function is simply not defined at $x_0$?

Comment: Oh, then it would be continuous on it's domain.

Comment: That's correct.  The definition of continuity requires the function to be defined.